# How can I return imutable reference types without break constness?

Tags: constants, d, type-safety

I have the following code in D:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.container.array;

class RefType { }

class MyContainer {
    private Array!RefType test;
    RefType result() const {  // I want const on this, not on return type
        return test[0];       // use opIndex() from Array(T)
        // Error: cannot implicitly convert expression (this.test.opIndex(0u)) 
        // of type const(RefType) to main.RefType
    }
}

int main(string[] argv) {
    auto c = new MyContainer; auto r = c.result(); return 0;
}
```

As you can see I want to return a reference type from a custom container class. But the opIndex() of Array is not giving the permission to do that, why?

I think that `opIndex()` should return a `RefType` instead of a `const(RefType)` value because the Array is `Array!RefType`.

Is this a bug? or is the design intention? If this is the intented design, how can I get that I want?

Comment: try replacing your `const` with `inout`. so `inout(RefType) result() inout { return test[0]; } ` and see if that works for you

Comment: Yes this works! but what is the meaning of the inout keyword?

Comment: I have tested and do not breaks the constness :)  please set fill it as answer. It is just I was finding.

Comment: `inout` can be used as a mutability placeholder for mutable, immutable and const, where it'll be allowed to accept any of them. However `inout` as parameters acts like `scope const` if I am correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think that opIndex() should return a RefType instead of a
>   const(RefType) value because the Array is Array!RefType.

No, this is wrong. When you define your memthod to be `const`, you have also specified that all members of the class are also const. This means that, no matter what type the member has in the definition, inside your `result` method they are (at least) `const`. As such, the compiler is completely justified in returning the error it is returning.

The usual (e.g. `C++`) way to resolve this is to define two (or, in D, three) overloads:

```d
RefType result() {
    return test[0];
}
RefType result() const {
    return test[0];
}
RefType result() immutable {
    return test[0];
}
```

So, one for the case the class is mutable, which returns a mutable reference. One for the case the class is const, which returns a const reference, and one for the case the class is immutable, which returns an immutable reference.

You will notice, however, that aside from the method decoration, all three implementations are precisely the same. To prevent you from defining three identical implementations, `D` has the `inout` modifier:

```d
RefType result() inout {
    return test[0];
}
```

This single definition replaces all three of the definitions above. As a rule of thumb, just write your definition as usual, but place `inout` any place you'd otherwise place `const`.

Comment: Ok, then I had a confusion yesterday. I want keep my container class unable to be modified but I dont want to prevent the users of modify the objects that container holds. Then no const nor immutable are useful in this case. right?

Comment: @JairoAndresVelascoRomero Yes, because `const` and `immutable` is transitive in D, neither of them apply to your use case. You will have to enforce the immutability of the collection itself at the API level.

Comment: When you return the RefType, it will also likely need to be `inout` because of the transitive const rules - inside the const/immutable/inout method, everything they reach through `this` is of the same type (or stronger). BTW sorry about not writing it up myself, been a busy weekend. But with that little nit, this answer should be good.

Comment: Ok, finally then my question should be "How to return mutable references from immutable containers?" and the answer is: you can't from `const` or `immutable` instances, but you can enforce the class immutability on API design.

Answer (score 1):

> I think that opIndex() should return a RefType instead of a 
>   const(RefType) value because the Array is Array!RefType.

This assumption is wrong. As your opIndex method is marked const. The implicitly given this reference is also const 
(is(this == const(MyContainer)). Which means that everything you access through it is also const, as D's const is transitive. As you access something const in your const method you will get something const. Returning something non-const from this method is illegal in D (luckily). The only things non-const that can be returned from a const method are value types without indirection.

A valid to make you type work as non-const, const and immutable you can write:

```
inout(RefType) result() inout { ... }
```

Comment: Yep, this is the way to go.